# List all the files in a depot?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to list all the files that are under the Perforce system in a tree . 
Can anyone please help me with the command that can list all the files ?

Ex:- I did `p4 sync`  So I want to know all the files that have been added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all of the files in the depot:

```
p4 files //...
```

If you want all of the files you have synced to your workspace:

```
p4 have
```